# python nested for loop keeps running indefinitely, yet the intended list is being created

Tags: python, pandas, nested

I have a dataframe called 'dft' of Netflix's TV Shows and movies, with a column, named "listed_in" with entries being a string of all the genres TV shows are classified under. Each row entry has multiple genre classification of different lengths. The genres are written as strings and separated by commas.

A single entry is something like, for example: 'Documentary','International TV Shows','Crime TV Shows'. Another row entry may have different number of genres it classifies under, some of who may be the same as some of the genres of other rows entries.

Now I want to create a list of the unique values in all the rows.

```
genres = []

for i in range(0,len(dft['listed_in'].str.split(','))):
    for j in range(0,len(dft['listed_in'].str.split(',')[i])):
        if (dft['listed_in'].str.split(',')[i][j]) not in genres:
            genres.append(dft['listed_in'].str.split(',')[i][j])
        else:
            pass
```

This keeps the kernel running indefinitely. But the thing is, the list is being created. If I interrupt the kernel after some time, and print the list its there.

Then, I create a dataframe out of this list with the intention of having a column with the count of times each genre appears in the original dataframe.

```
data = {'Genres':genres,'count':[0 for i in range(0,len(genres))]}
gnr = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
```

Then to change the count column to each genre's count of occurrence:

```
for i in range(0,65):
    for j in range(0,514):
        if gnr.loc[i,'Genres'] in (dft['listed_in'].str.split(',').index[j]):
            gnr.loc[i,'count'] = gnr.loc[i,'count'] + dft['listed_in'].str.split(',').value_counts()[j]
        else:
            pass
```

Then again this code keeps running indefinitely, but after interrupting it I saw the count for the 1st entry was updated in the gnr dataframe.

I don't know what is happening.

Comment: What is the result of `len(dft['listed_in'].str.split(','))`? Please read [ask] and [mre], and make it possible for others to observe the problem. What you describe makes no sense; if the code seems to be hanging/busy computing the results, then interrupting it should leave only partial results. That said, it is a good idea to make sure you are familiar with how Python's `for` loops work, and avoid abusing `range`.

Comment: 8807, which is the length of the original column. ```dft['listed_in'].str.split(',')``` is creating a pandas Series with each entry being a list of all the genres for that particular rows TV show or Movie.

Comment: Can you still cause the problem if you use a small dataset?

Comment: I've restarted python and Jupyter twice now, and the results are same. I'm running a 2019 MacBook Pro i7 with 16GB ram. Latest python.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No other issues on operations on this or any other dataset, small or large.

Comment: Again, please read [mre]. We can only help understand the problem if we know *what is actually needed in order to cause the problem*.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a minimal input which causes this loop?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the process actually hangs? For loops with pandas is much slower than you would expect especially with the number of iterations you are doing (65*514). If you haven't already id put in a print(i) so you get some insight as to what iteration you're on